# hql Not supported for DML operations

Tags: hibernate, model, hql, sql-update

i am trying to update the query but this error keep coming:

```
public List<Object[]> rosterGrdUpdate(String stuBunValue, String stuGrdValue, String pcID, String crsCd) {
List<Object[]> updateRosterInfo = null;
java.util.Date today = new java.util.Date();
Date Date_toDay = new java.sql.Date(today.getTime());
String modifyFlagUpdate = "U";
String modifyFlagWh = "N";
Query querySt  = null;
String sql1 = "update WgRoster wr set wr.grade= :gr, wr.modify_flag= :mf, wr.grade_date= :gd, wr.user_id= :ud" +
" where wr.stubun= :stb and wr.crs_cd= :cr and wr.modify_flag !=  :mfu";
querySt  = session.createQuery(sql1);
querySt.setParameter("gr", stuGrdValue);
querySt.setParameter("mf", modifyFlagUpdate);
querySt.setParameter("gd", Date_toDay);
querySt.setParameter("ud", pcID);
querySt.setParameter("stb", stuBunValue);
querySt.setParameter("cr", crsCd);
querySt.setParameter("mfu", modifyFlagWh);  
int res = querySt.executeUpdate();  
return  (List<Object[]>)querySt.list();
```

any suggestion would be appreciated.

Comment: I have been searching in Google on this but no luck so far. Please suggest if you find anything I am missing.

Comment: shevchik I resolved the issue. I was a problem with compound key mapping with the DB.

Comment: please add you solution below and check it as correct

Comment: If you resolve your problem Delete your Question...

Answer (score 0):

The `querySt` object can support only `executeUpdate()` given the nature of operation. Remove `querySt.list()`. Make another query, namely

```
query  = session.createQuery("from WgRoster");
```

and then call `query.list();`